# Contacting a API from a service that has a api code in it

Tags: angular, api, mean

I have the following set up in ExpressJs on my back-end. I have the api included as a var which is then added to the end of the call

```
router.get('http://localhost:4000/api/v2/create?password=:pass&email=:emailAddress&label=:username$api_code=' + apiCode, function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body); 
    if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
            message: 'Error while fetching data!'
        });
    }
    res.status(200).json({
        data: wallet
    });
});
```

I want my angular2 service to use this API to create an new bitcoin wallet and then return the json to angular2 to display and save in mongo.

```
createWallet(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/v2/create')
            .map( (data: Response) => {
                const extracted = data.json();
                console.log(extracted);
            });
    }
```

How to I call the url route and still be able to leave out the api code?

```
"http://localhost:3000/api/v2/create?password=" + pass+ "&email=" + email + "&label=" + username"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like :

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/v2/create',{ password : pass , email : email , label : username  })
```